# Getting client ip using Knative and Anthos

Tags: kubernetes, istio, google-cloud-run, knative

We use Google Cloud Run on our K8s cluster on GCP which is powered by Knative and Anthos, however it seems the load balancer doesn't amend the x-forwarded-for (and this is not expected as it is TCP load balancer), and Istio doesn't do the same.

Do you have the same issue or it is limited to our deployment?
I understand Istio support this as part of their upcoming [Gateway Network Topology](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/) but not in the current gcp version.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct in assessing that current Cloud Run for Anthos set up (unintentionally) does not let you see the origin IP address of the user.

As you said, the created gateway for Istio/Knative in this case is a Cloud Network Load Balancer (TCP) and this LB doesn’t preserve the client’s IP address on a connection when the traffic is routed to Kubernetes Pods (due to how Kubernetes networking works with iptables etc). That’s why you see an `x-forwarded-for` header, but it contains internal hops (e.g. 10.x.x.x).

I am following up with our team on this. It seems that it was not noticed before.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. I guess that's exactly it, however [some](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs/issues/942) have pointed out that changing the load balancer (istio-ingress) `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local` actually fix the issue, however it would be great to know if such change have any side effects as it skip the cluster feature and "[risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip)".

Comment: It indeed would have such a side effect for Kubernetes. However, in Knative case the traffic is being sent to gateway pods and there’s only a few of those (if ever more than 1). If you don’t have high QPS, this would be fine. Otherwise, it might be a problem. I recommend testing/validating under pressure.

Comment: Sorry for late update. This local seem to work fine when dealing with few requests, however it result in a some timeouts once the load increase. Would be ideal to see a solution directly from Cloud Run.

Comment: Hey @AhmetB-Google - We are facing the same issue with could run and anthos. Please, is there any progress or a solution for this issue?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Do we have any updates on this @AhmetB-Google? Thanks

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Do we have any updates on this @AhmetAlpBalkan Thanks.